# How to get all the word using a match from the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My string is :

```
str = {!Chirag patel&gt;1|2|3|4|5}<br /><br />asdadasd<br /><br />{!Test&gt;T|E|S|T}<br /><br />Chirag patel<br /><br />{!HELLO&gt;H|E|L|L|O}
```

How i will get below result using a str.match in array:

```
0: Chirag patel&gt;1|2|3|4|5
1: Test&gt;T|E|S|T
2: HELLO&gt;H|E|L|L|O
```

I already tried below code:

```
str.match(/^{![^}]+}+/g);
```

but it give me only one match , but i want all the match

I want to replce my find word using like as below.

if i find : `Chirag patel&gt;1|2|3|4|5`

then i want a below code is replace in to the string.

```
    <div><select class="template-field" data-field-name="chirag patel">
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
<option value="">3</option>
<option value="">4</option>
<option value="">5</option>
</select></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do as follows;

```js
var str = "{!Chirag patel&gt;1|2|3|4|5}<br /><br />asdadasd<br /><br />{!Test&gt;T|E|S|T}<br /><br />Chirag patel<br /><br />{!HELLO&gt;H|E|L|L|O}",
matches = str.match(/[^\{!]+(?=\})/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: `str.match(/[^\{]+(?=\})/g)` replace with this `str.match(/[^\{!]+(?=\})/g)` , and i will accept your answer

Comment: can you do one more favor me , How can i replace all this finds word list in to the string?

Comment: @chirag patel you can do like `var newStr = str.replace(/[^\{!]+(?=\})/g,"replacementString");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123788/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-redu).

Answer (score 0):

First we need more infos, about what you have already tried, what do you really want, ect, even if i undertsand what's your main goal, explain more please!

And wich langage do you use? HTML, okay, i'am not stupid, but do you use nodejs, angular, simple javascript, jQuery??

Anyway, you should take a look at the javascript ".split" method, if you pass "`<br />`" as the spliting argument you should get what you want.